# Bannister: fix akimbo short top part

Tags: stairs

[image]

[image]

[image]The little part of the top floor bannister is askew.  It has periodically done this over the years, always been an issue with this little part.  Rest of the bannister has been solid over the decades.  But this little part just has one screw or what have you (can't see) holding it do the metal.  And then the joint is glued to other piece.

How to fix it?  Reglue it?  Screw it somehow from peice to piece (how)...and then will there be a rough part that catches the hand?  Other idea?

I'm pretty tool idiot, so appreciate full explanation of what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the short piece rotated out of position (as in the photos) drill a hole down, through the metal part and then rotate the short wooden piece back into position.

If necessary, drill a smaller diameter hole up through the hole you just made into the wooden piece of appropriate size to allow a wood screw to be installed through the metal up into the wood.

Comment: That makes all kinds of sense!  "Other idea" wins the day.  Gotta see if my drill will go through metal...but otherwise, gut!

Comment: It's pretty thick steel and my drill is not that powerful.  Will go buy a steel cutting bit.